# System (Still) Fails at Times to Notify the OP When an Answer is Posted

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE**: After not being notified of both answers today that were posted to my question: [How to Display the Page Number Only (No Header) for Chapter Pages; Header Only, Elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631553/how-to-display-the-page-number-only-no-header-for-chapter-pages-header-only). I have added this as an update.

Original Post:

I have noticed over the past week that I am not always notified by the system that an answer has been posted to my question.

The first instance that I noticed was [Putting a Code to the Right of an Item in a New Enumerate Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616073/putting-a-code-to-the-right-of-an-item-in-a-new-enumerate-environment).

The second occurred yesterday (first posted answer): [\Scalefont Not Scaling (Strictly) Monotonically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616743/scalefont-not-scaling-strictly-monotonically)

Has anyone had a similar experience?

Does anyone know what is or mighty be) causing this malfunction?

Comment: Perhaps @egreg can comment on this as well? ;)

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @Werner I haven't knowingly encountered the problem since.

Comment: @Werner  Yes; actually today, I was only notified once regarding this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631553/how-to-display-the-page-number-only-no-header-for-chapter-pages-header-only/631557#631557 that someone had posted an answer. I'm not sure which answer it was that I was not notified about, but I think in may have been Simon Dispa's answer. Thanks.